# Dynamically load and change graphics

Tags: flash, actionscript, graphics

I would like to do something like this:

The flash project loads any vector graphic object from hard disc (that graphic has only two color), change one color (for ex #ff0000) to an other (for ex #00ff00) and display.

Is it possible?

If it is, what is the file format of this graphic object?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load vector graphics, the easiest, natively supported way in Flash is to load a SWF file. That SWF file can either have graphics in the root display list (in which case you can simply add the loaded SWF, which will come in as a MovieClip, to your display list) or it can define symbols that are linked to class names. In the latter case, you can get the class definitions using `getDefinitionByName()` and then instantiate that class.

```
// After having loaded a SWF with class definition "MySymbol"
var symbolClass : Class = getDefinitionByName("MySymbol") as Class;
var symbol : Sprite = new symbolClass();
```

As for the color transformation, you might be able to do it using the `ColorTransform` or `ColorMatrixFilter` classes, depending on the similarity of the two colors. Otherwise, the easiest way if you're sticking with the SWF-loading method would be to simply separate the two parts of your graphic into two separate layers/display objects when you generate the SWF file (e.g. in Flash Professional) and then access them and transform them separately.

```
var symbol : MovieClip = new symbolClass;
symbol.part1.transform.colorTransform = 
                        new ColorTransform(0, 0, 0, 1, 255, 0, 0);
```

This code will access the child of the `MySymbol` MovieClip with instance name `part1` and change it's color to red. For more information on ColorTransform, see [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html).